# Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6 на Openserver

Tags: mysql, openserver

OpenServer 5.2.2
В этот прекрасный день отказался запускаться.

```
   2017-09-30 11:02:39  --------------------------------------------
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление Hosts файла
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление конфигурации PHP-5.6
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Обновление конфигурации Apache-2.4+Nginx-1.10
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Запуск MySQL-5.6
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Запуск Apache-2.4+Nginx-1.10
2017-09-30 11:02:39  Проверка состояния сервера
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Сбой запуска!
2017-09-30 11:03:13  --------------------------------------------
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Остановка системных модулей
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Отключение виртуального диска
2017-09-30 11:03:13  Сервер успешно остановлен за 0,218 секунд!



 2017-09-30 11:02:39 0 [Note] c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 3236 ...
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 4372925 and 4372925 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 4372935 in the ib_logfiles!
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 3236 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    2017-09-30 11:02:39 e98  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
    InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\ther.ibd
    InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
    InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
    InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
    InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
    InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
    InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
    InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
    InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
    InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
    InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
    InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была ошибка во время работы базы или просто некорректно закрыли программу.
Попробуйте Дополнительно -> Конфигураций -> My-SQL(какой у вас запущен) ->
в самом низу прописать " innodb_force_recovery = 3 " и заново запустить OpenServer.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй изменить язык Винды на английский, возможно это проблемы с кодировкой. Панель управления - Региональные стандарты - Формат изменяешь на Анлийский или Язык интерфейса Windows - Вкладка дополнительно - Язык программ не поддерживающих Юникод - Английский - Убери галочку с Бета версия (эсли есть). **Мне помогло.**

Comment: Спасибо. помогло и мне. Снял галку и всё заработало. Язык с русского на англ. переключать не пришлось.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже не сработало, но сработало когда я:

В "Панель управления\Часы  и регион" и регион В разделе "Изменение форматов даты, времени и чисел"

В разделе "Дополнительно" Нажал кнопку "Изменить Язык системы...", убрал галочку с "Использовать Юникод..."
И переустановил Open Server на Английский язык

И всё!!!

Answer (score 0):

Дурдом какой-то. Для того, чтобы работала MySQL Workbench нужно поставить галочку "Бета версия. Использовать Юникод для поддержки языка во всем мире" в разделе часы и регионы - региональные стандарты - дополнительно.

Но у вас отвалится MySQL в OpenServere. Для OpenServere эту галочку нужно наоборот снять.